# ImportError: No module named 'django' uWSGI Django Nginx Ubuntu 16.04 Python3.6

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi

I've spent a day trying to figure this out.

I'm running on `Digital Ocean` with `Django`, `Python3.6`, `Nginx`, `Ubuntu 16.04`, and `uWSGI`.

Have had to install `Python3.6` via `deadsnakesppa` and have a `virtualenv` which I created with

```
mkvirtualenv --python=python3.6 myproject
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#top) which I have followed before but when I try to run the below code to test the application server (not in virtualenv)

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/myproject --chdir /home/user/myproject/src/myproject -w myproject.wsgi
```

I get this traceback

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Aug  5 12:23:53 2019] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 05 August 2019 11:53:48
os: Linux-4.4.0-157-generic #185-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 23 09:17:01 UTC 2019
nodename: myproject
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/user/myproject/src/myproject
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3898
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8080 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 17338)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:34660 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x21aaf90
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72904 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 17337, cores: 1)
```

I get the same when I activate the virtualenv.

Further error logs are

`Aug 05 12:18:20 myproject uwsgi[16998]: --- no python application found, check your system...`

```
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor service.
Aug 05 11:39:47 wmyproject systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: Stopped uWSGI Emperor service.
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor service...
Aug 05 11:39:47 myproject systemd[14970]: uwsgi.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: No such file or directory
```

If I run the below (not inside a virtualenv)

```
python3 -c 'import django.core.wsgi'
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

but if I run it within a virtualenv I get no error, which means the error has to do with `uWSGI`.

Running `python manage.py runserver` from my `manage.py` level works fine.

`pip3 -V` gives `pip 19.2.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

and `python3.6 -V` gives `Python 3.6.9`

I've tried re-installing uWSGI with `sudo -H pip3 install uwsgi` and it always seems to install to the `python 3.5 site-packages`.

If I run `pip3 install uwsgi` inside the virtualenv it installs to

```
Uninstalling uWSGI-2.0.18:
  Would remove:
    /home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi
    /home/user/Env/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uWSGI-2.0.18.dist-info/*
    /home/user/Env/myproject/l

ib/python3.6/site-packages/uwsgidecorators.py
```

my .ini file

```
[uwsgi]
project = myproject
uid = user
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)/src/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

My `File: /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown user:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My project obviously needs python3.6 to run and I am out of solutions, can anyone please offer any advice?

Comment: The error is saying that django isn't installed in the environment you're running. So, as you did, you *should* run everything *inside* the virtualenv where django is installed (make sure you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` or wherever your list of required packages is inside the virtualenv).

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for your reply. I've tried running that again but it comes up as all `requirements are already satisfied.` in `/home/user/Env/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: Just read a similar question elsewhere with a comment `The problem was that the system-wide python version linked to uwsgi needs to be the same as the one of the virtualenv, which, I think, is a very stupid thing.` although I've tried getting uwsgi to run python3.6 and it still runs 3.5

Comment: ah, if you installed uWSGI globally (using the system-wide python) then yes, it's not going to work if your virtualenv is using a different python. Why don't install uwsgi *inside* your virtualenv and then run *that specific* uwsgi? So instead of `uwsgi --ini ...` you run `/home/user/Env/bin/uwsgi --ini ...`

Comment: I was just going to say I've run `uwsgi --http :8080 --module myproject.wsgi` from within my `virtualenv` at the `manage.py` level and it works, but does that mean my ini file needs to be altered? Because it obviously doesn't load when I quit that command.

Comment: You .ini file looks fine, just make sure it's launched with the correct uwsgi (with the command I gave in my previous comment).

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for your answer Dirk, it runs perfectly. Although (I know I am asking slightly beyond the question here) when I try to start the uwsgi emperor service with my config I've added above, the pages don't load. I've changed the `ExecStart` to the uwsgi virtualenv path but I still get a `--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---`

Comment: Which must mean that the path isn't being found still?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197503/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-trilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using two different versions of python on your system (your system-wide python seems to be 3.5.2) then you should `pip install uwsgi` *inside* the virtualenv that contains the version of python you're going to use.

And then you should launch *that specific* uwsgi by using the path to it directly, in your case */home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi*:

```
> /home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi --ini /path/to/file/uwsgi.ini
```

or

```
> /home/user/Env/myproject/bin/uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/myproject --chdir /home/user/myproject/src/myproject -w myproject.wsgi
```